# Composite rotation of two rotation matrixes

Tags: matrices, rotations

I have a scenario where a camera is mounted to an aircraft. For this camera, I have the attitude correction values i.e. misalignment angles, namely, yaw, pitch, and roll. Also, I have the yaw, pitch, roll, of the aircraft at the time of aerial photos are taken. In addition, I have the camera position, and the position of the aircraft for each image. I'd like to know how can I obtain the effective rotation angle, so that I can apply the pinhole camera model for my images in determining the geocoordinates of my images.

Working formulas as well as theories around this problem is also highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Euler angles to rotation matrices and then multiply them together

$$ R_\text{air} \mathrm{rot}(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) $$

and

$$ R_\text{cam} = \mathrm{rot}(u,v,r) $$

and then combine them to get

$$ R_\text{combined} = R_{\rm air} R_{\rm cam}  $$

<sub>Here ${}^\intercal$ is the matrix transpose which inverts the rotation.</sub>

to get the relative position of the aircraft to the camera. Finally convert from rotation matrix back to Euler angles.

$$ (a,b,c) = \mathrm{rot}^{-1} ( R_{\rm combined} ) $$

Comment: thanks for this answer. so Rrelative means, camera orientation with respect to the earth? am it correct here?

Comment: Also, I'd like to know the order of the multiplication, is it, R_transpose_camera (dotproduct) R_aircraft, or the other way. many thanks!

Comment: @CoolCK Actually, your question isn't descriptive enough to answer. When you have euler angles, what reference frame are they measured from? My answer assumes that they are both referencing to the earth, and thus in the inversion (transpose) to get back to the camera frame.

Comment: @CoolCK the order depends on the convention used. I use the _columns_ of $R$ as the direction vectors of the coordinate frame and not the rows. Anyway, that is the whole point of using rotation matrices is that they combine relatively easily. The same goes for quaternions also.

Comment: in my case, the camera rotations are with respect to the aircraft. The angles are introduced as "misalignment angles" (attitude corrections)", and I have the rotation angles of the aircraft with respect to the earth. For me to apply "pinhole model", I need to find the camera rotation with respect to earth. I hope this is clear. thanks!

Comment: could you please elaborate your answer according to my circumstances. I hope above description is clear.

Comment: @CoolCK see answer update then.

Comment: @CoolCK you multiply them left to right in order from ground to camera.

Comment: many thanks. Now I understood. in the case if both camera rotations and plane rotations are given with respect to earth, then I have to take the transpose of camera and multiply it with aircraft's rotation matrix. For my work, I have to follow this specific (i.e. taking relative rotation via dot product.) many thanks!